# How to return ajax response with error http code from PrestaShop ModuleFrontController?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I start working with PrestaShop 1.7.6 (before I worked with Symfony) and I write few custom modules to PrestaShop, but now I want send json data from my front controller module to user. Everything works fine if I send json with http code 200, but now I want send error message with proper http code (e.g 400). In Symfony I can do that by using JsonResponse (I try to do that here but it's not working as expected).I saw in presta controller are just two methods with ajax response (ajaxDie - which is deprecated and ajaxRender), but both of them doesn't takes as parameter http code response and always send 200.

```
    if (!$product) {
         $json = Tools::jsonEncode(['status' => false]);
         $this->ajaxRender($json);

         //return new JsonResponse($json, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);// doesn't send proper code
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to send error code from module front controller which extends ModuleFrontController?? Now only possible to me action is send error message with http code 200 (but I think it's bad idea to send error with that code). Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to send and receive data using AJAX is displayed below.
More information can be found at [Prestashop Docs](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/)

**Ajax post**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        url: 'linktoyourfile.php',
        data: { action: 'getMyrequest' },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.result);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

**Module Front Controler**

```
    class TestModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
    {
        public function init()
        {
            parent::init();
        }

        public function displayAjaxGetMyrequest()
        {
            // ERROR HANDELING
            if ($this->errors) {
                die(Tools::jsonEncode(array('hasError' => true, 'errors' => $this->errors)));
            } else {
                echo Tools::json_encode(array('result' => 'test result'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I send ajax by generate link inside module and pass it to js by: "         Media::addJsDef(array(
            'add_product_link' => Context::getContext()->link->getModuleLink('ps_compareproducts', 'add', ['ajax' => true]),
        ));" and connection works fine (I can get data and proccess it). The problem is when I want set http response code to 400 inside e.g  displayAjaxGetMyrequest() method and change data format from "json" to "json+problem".

Comment: I have updated my code, does this do what you want now? (you can use php to read the error and send a custom error code)

Comment: I found answer for my problem and I updated my post with solution of it. Thx anyway for help :)